# video.js auto quality switcher depends on bandwidth, like youtube.com

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, video.js

I'm using videojs  in my page.
I have 3 version of my video (1080p,720p,480p) with .mp4 format.
I'm searching for best way (must popular, simple, clean) that player select file depends on bandwidth on auto mode, and show a menu to select quality manually.

I searched in google. but no sample i found.

Answer (score 0):

Payers with adaptive bitrate selection use a format like HLS or DASH and are not compatible to standard mp4 files. Switching between mp4s is EXTREAMLY complicated, so its avoided.

Comment: what's the best plugin for HLS or Dash, that support adaptive bitrate selection ?

I found some think in this page, but i don't know which one is the best?
https://github.com/videojs/video.js/wiki/Plugins

Comment: personally I like plyr.io

Comment: Video.js supports HLS and DASH ABR out of the box. No additional plugin is needed.

Comment: @misterben

I change the Source from .mp4 to .m3u8 (i convert video using ffmpeg to multi quality) and Video.js play video very good, and automatically change the quality depends on bandwidth, but don't show any option to select quality manually, how can i solve this problem?

Comment: @sadegh have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

@sadegh and @Badrani

You can use video-js-contrib-quality-levels package for the automatic quality selection

Comment: Please read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and update your answer.